# How to animate a typing text effect in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Written some script to give the effect of typing text but I want each character to fade in. Ive tried adding x.style.opacity and getting the element by Id but this changes the whole thing is there any way to target the individual characters? Here is my code:

```
var i = -1; 
var string = "BREAKING NEWS "
var array = string.split("");   


function Next(){
i++;   
if(i > (array.length - 1)){      
    i = 0;                            
}
setTimeout('Slide()',50);
 }


 function Slide(){
x = document.getElementById('test')
x.innerHTML += array[i];

setTimeout('Next()',50);
```

}

Comment: can't fade in text itself, wrap letters in span tags and fade those in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't target single characters you need to wrap them in a tag, like span:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Quadraxas/37usj/2/)

```
function Slide() {
    var sp = document.createElement('span');
    sp.setAttribute('class', 'fadein');
    sp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));
    x.appendChild(sp);
    setTimeout('Next()', 50);
}
```

and you can animate them with css animations

```
.fadein {
    animation: fadein 2s;
}
@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Copied answer from your jsfiddle but its not working properly its doubling up each character, any ideas why?

Comment: do you still have the problem? note that i slightly changed your code, especially Next function decl, you may want to revert that change.

Comment: Yeah still having the problem, thanks for the help its given me a lot to think about if I fix it ill post it.

Comment: Works great know I was calling the Next() function onload as well